# JAVA SERIALIZATION & DESERIALIZTION: Of two separate objects that have their own array lists under one file

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, serialization, deserialization

I'm currently having some trouble serialising and deserialising (my suspicion is that serialisation is the problem) Two ArrayLists for two separate objects. ArrayList1 (for object1) and ArrayList2 (for object2) Need to both be stored under the same file but unfortunately it doesn't seem to work.

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Object1 implements Serializable {

    public int num;
    String name;
    String id;

    public BeanBagObject(int num,String, String name,String id){
        this.num = num;
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
  //get method
    public int getNum(){return this.num;}
    public String getName(){return this.name;}
    public String getId(){return this.id;}
}
```

Included in the file also is:

```
public static ObjectArrayList Object1List = new ObjectArrayList();
public static ObjectArrayList Object2List = new ObjectArrayList();
```

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Object2 implements Serializable {

    public int num;
    int TwoNumber;
    String id;

    public ReservationObject(int num,int TwoNumber,String id){
        this.num = num;
        this.TwoNumber = TwoNumber;
        this.id = id;
    }
    //get method
    public int getNum(){return this.num;}
    public int getTwoNumber(){return this.TwoNumber;}
    public String getID(){return this.id;}

}
```

```
public void saveStoreContents(String filename) throws IOException {
            try{
                FileOutputStream fos= new FileOutputStream(filename);
                ObjectOutputStream oos= new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
                oos.writeObject(Object1List);
                oos.writeObject(Object2List);
                oos.close();
                fos.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();//Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream.
            }
        }
```

```
public void loadStoreContents(String filename) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
            ArrayList<String> arraylist= new ArrayList<String>();
            try
            {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
                ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
                arraylist = (ArrayList) ois.readObject();
                ois.close();
                fis.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                ioe.printStackTrace();
                return;
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException c){
                System.out.println("Class not found");
                c.printStackTrace();//Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream.
                return;
            }
            for(String str: arraylist){
                System.out.println(str);
            }
    }
```

**This seems fine but its printing the objectarraylist with an ID, not the actual content, no clue why :((((**
Any help would be **greatly** appreciated, thanks ppl :)

Comment: what error do you get? what exactly does not work? what is `Object1List` ? can you show the class of it?

Comment: its printing the objectarraylist with an ID, not the actual content

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print the contents of the object instead of the object id then you need to implement the `public String toString();` method.  Using your code it might look like this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

class Scratch {
    public static List<ReservationObject> objectList1 = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<BeanBagObject> objectList2 = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scratch scratch = new Scratch();
        objectList1.add(new ReservationObject(1, 2, "id"));
        objectList2.add(new Scratch.BeanBagObject(1, "name", "id"));
        try {
            scratch.saveStoreContents("test");
            scratch.loadStoreContents("test");
        } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void loadStoreContents(String filename) throws IOException,
            ClassNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<ReservationObject> arraylist1;
        ArrayList<BeanBagObject> arraylist2;
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(filename);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            arraylist1 = (ArrayList<ReservationObject>) ois.readObject();
            arraylist2 = (ArrayList<BeanBagObject>) ois.readObject();
            ois.close();
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException c) {
            System.out.println("Class not found");
            c.printStackTrace();//Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream.
            return;
        }
        for (ReservationObject reservationObject : arraylist1) {
            System.out.println(reservationObject);
        }
        for (BeanBagObject beanBagObject : arraylist2) {
            System.out.println(beanBagObject);
        }
    }

    public void saveStoreContents(String filename) throws IOException {
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            oos.writeObject(objectList1);
            oos.writeObject(objectList2);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();//Prints this throwable and its backtrace to the standard error stream.
        }
    }

    public static class ReservationObject implements Serializable {

        public int num;
        int TwoNumber;
        String id;

        public ReservationObject(int num, int TwoNumber, String id) {
            this.num = num;
            this.TwoNumber = TwoNumber;
            this.id = id;
        }

        //get method
        public int getNum() {
            return this.num;
        }

        public int getTwoNumber() {
            return this.TwoNumber;
        }

        public String getID() {
            return this.id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "ReservationObject{" +
                    "num=" + num +
                    ", TwoNumber=" + TwoNumber +
                    ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }

    public static class BeanBagObject implements Serializable {

        public int num;
        String name;
        String id;

        public BeanBagObject(int num, String name, String id) {
            this.num = num;
            this.name = name;
            this.id = id;
        }

        //get method
        public int getNum() {
            return this.num;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return this.name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return this.id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "BeanBagObject{" +
                    "num=" + num +
                    ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                    ", id='" + id + '\'' +
                    '}';
        }
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
ReservationObject{num=1, TwoNumber=2, id='id'}
BeanBagObject{num=1, name='name', id='id'}
```

Comment: I'm confronted with:Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.ArrayList<beanbags.ReservationObject>'

Comment: What line? the above runs perfectly for me in Java8

Comment: the lines are line 32 & 33

Comment: arraylist1 = (ArrayList<ReservationObject>) ois.readObject();
            arraylist2 = (ArrayList<BeanBagObject>) ois.readObject();

Comment: Ohh that's just a warning that you are attempting to cast an `Object` to an typed `ArrayList` it doesn't mean it will fail at runtime.  Did you run the code?  Depending on your IDE you can disable the warning by placing this above the offending lines of code: `//noinspection unchecked`

Comment: error message:    java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid type code: 04
line:   arraylist1 = (ArrayList<ReservationObject>) ois.readObject();

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error the above runs without exceptions for me on `java version "1.8.0_181"`

Comment: is there a way I can private message u in some way?